# 403 : Insufficient Permission while creating an folder in google drive api php

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client, create-directory

I'm implementing google drive api to implement in my application. I did that all code configuration from google-drive-client-php documentation. But I got an this permission error. Please give me any hint for this:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig('client_secrets.json');
    $client->setAccessType("offline");

    $client->setScopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");

    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
        $drive = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
        $fileMetaData = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
            'name' => 'RootFolder',
            'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'));

        $parentFolder = $drive->files->create($fileMetaData, array(
            'fields' => 'id'
        ));

        $permission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
        $permission->setValue('me');
        $permission->setType('anyone');
        $permission->setRole('writer');

        $drive->permissions->insert($parentFolder->getId(), $permission);
        echo "<pre>";
        echo json_encode($parentFolder);

    } else {
        $redirect_uri = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/callback.php';
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

Thank u :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so you are requesting ...

```
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
```

while you actually might require ...

```
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
```

for reference, here's the mapping of the API scopes:

```
/** View and manage the files in your Google Drive. */
const DRIVE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";

/** View and manage its own configuration data in your Google Drive. */
const DRIVE_APPDATA = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata";

/** View and manage Google Drive files and folders that you have opened or created with this app. */
const DRIVE_FILE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file";

/** View and manage metadata of files in your Google Drive. */
const DRIVE_METADATA = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata";

/** View metadata for files in your Google Drive. */
const DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly";

/** View the photos, videos and albums in your Google Photos. */
const DRIVE_PHOTOS_READONLY = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly";

/** View the files in your Google Drive. */
const DRIVE_READONLY = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly";

/** Modify your Google Apps Script scripts' behavior. */
const DRIVE_SCRIPTS = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts";
```

Comment: Thanks Martin...:)

Answer (score 0):

I got an solution for my problem

Remove

> $permission->setValue('me');

and change this Permission method to

> $drive->permissions->insert($parentFolder->getId(), $permission);

To

> $drive->files->create($fileMetaData, array('fields' => 'id'));

Here in the google drive api insert an setValue() method is deprecated so it was not work.

Comment: this does not appear to be the solution, because with the access-scope you've requested you just cannot write to the Drive, but can only read meta-data. please see my answer; hope this makes sense.